# Wordpress REST API 401 error when fetching menus

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

I'm trying to fetch menus data from rest api but I get 401 error that i have no permission to see this.

I use wp-json/wp/v2/menus

I tried to replace files to that files but it doesn't fix that https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/pull/1863/commits/f5b19db1e2cf7295135e3e06912618c86af91cc6

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used wp api menus wordpress plugin. Tested and working on Wordpress 5.9.x